# Halting an activity until I get result from an AlertDialog

Tags: android

Here is my problem - I want to create an activity and a dialog (with text field and OK button). I want to do the following:

1. Show the AlertDialog (on creation of the activity, on clicking a button, or some other actions);
2. Fill the text in the AlertDialog, and click the OK button;
3. Continue doing the main thread of the activity;

Something like this:

```
public String getText() {

    String result = null;

    // Showing the new window with the text box and the button, and after
    // the button is clicked to move to the return statement below;

    return result;
}
```

I tried using "runOnUiThread" and "AsyncTask", but the actions on the field "result" are done only in the "protected void onPostExecute(Void result)" method, and meanwhile the main program is still executing, without waiting for my input.

Is there anyway this to be done (I am sure it has, because saw such apps) to solve this problem? I know that is really impudent to ask for such help - but is is possible to write some code example, just to see how it is really happening, because more than 3 days, I can' do it. If not please give some suggestions, and will continue trying and trying :)
THANKS A LOT!

Comment: What is running on your "main" thread?

Comment: May be my explanation was not correct - I want to make the program wait for any further actions until the text in the field is entered and the OK button is clicked.
In this case I am waiting the user to enter a text, so send a correct HTTP Request.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the operations u want to perform after click ,write in asynctask .When dialog button clicked execute the asynctask.Thats it

Answer (score 0):

Well that's pretty much how dialogs work anyway.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

At the bottom it shows how to create a custom dialog.

However, a lot of the time the text you need to take in is also displayed on the activity anyway, could you not embed an EditText on your activity and simplify this task?

Comment: Yes - this is absolutely clear, but the thing that is hard for me to do, is to make the activity to wait for the clicking the OK button of the AlertDialog (or any other custom one).

Comment: What exactly is the activity doing while the dialog is up?

Comment: Waiting for the text to be entered (or not) and the button is clicked.

Comment: The problem is that I can't make the activity to wait until this is done and after that continue with the result.

Comment: the alertdialog runs on the "main" thread... what is your activity doing that you want to stop?

Comment: The activity is sending HTTP request, which needs some information from the text field (and a lot more which is taken previously). When the AlertDialog shows, the activity should pause for a moment until the info is taken, and after that to sent the request.

Comment: What is there to pause? the activity isn't doing anything from what you describe.

Comment: Just imagine the thing that you need something to be done, just after the dialog is shown and the OK button is clicked.

Comment: Then you have that done on the listener of the alertdialog. When the user clicks ok, the alert dialog fires off an call to the listener and from there you can trigger your http request.